# What could explain the myth (or truth) of drunken defenders during the battle of the plains of Abraham?

Tags: cultural-history, 18th-century, colonial-america, canada, quebec

I have come across popular references towards the sodden or sozzled state of the French and Canadien defenders of Quebec City during the [Battle of the Plains of Abraham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Plains_of_Abraham). Mostly, these references are made by the loosing side or their descendants. It would seem, according to them, that the loss of the battle is to be attributed to the intoxicated state of either the soldiers themselves or their commander; [Louis-Joseph de Montcalm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis-Joseph_de_Montcalm). Examples of this provided below:

From "Mon Pays" by "Les Cowboys Fringants"

> [...]
>
> Sur les plaines d'Abraham, l'armée **trinquait à l'eau d'vie** /
> *On the plains of Abraham, the army was a **toasting with spirits***
>
> Tout en bas de la falaise, les Anglais prenaient fusils /
> *Down below the cliff, the English readied their guns*
>
> [...]
>
> Si Montcalm avait pas été **saoûl** /
> *Had Montcalm not been **drunk***
>
> Si l'armée avait pas **pris un coup** /
> *Had the army not been **four sheets to the wind***
>
> Les Anglais feraient à peine le Waterloo! /
> *The English would have barely made it to Waterloo*

Translations in italics by me, emphasis mine.

From "La Cohorte Fantôme" by Frédérique Champagne

> Cadavres fleur­de­li­sés sur les plaines d’Abra­ham / *Bodies bearing the fleur de lys on the Plains of Abraham*
>
> Mont­calm tiré dans le dos / *Montcalm shot in the back*
>
> Vergor **saoul mort** capturé blessé à mort à l’Anse-au-Foulon / *Vergor **blind drunk** captured mortally wounded at Anse-au-Foulon*

Translations in italics by me, emphasis mine. To wit, Vergor was the French officer in charge of the defense of Anse-au-Foulon.

Other examples crop up every now and again in public discourse, articles or other media.

So what is the source of this myth that the defenders at Quebec in 1759 were drunk on duty while a known enemy force was nearby? Or is there any truth to these claims? Scholarly work on the subject of the battle seems to suggest that Montcalm blundered when he did not wait for reinforcements before attacking.

I am aware that during this period people would consume what was referred to as [small beer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_beer) (less than 2.8 % ABV) as a means of hydration which was free from pathogens, soldiers were even [allotted a ration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_soldiers_in_the_eighteenth_century#Food) of this, could it be that the such historical practices are being conflated with more modern perceptions of beer consumption?

Or is it that such claims as to the intoxication of the loosing side are simply a modern interpretation of the events which shifts the blame for the loss onto other factors than martial prowess, strategy, tactics, logistics and luck that make up the sum of war?

Comment: According to https://archive.org/details/siegeofquebecbat06doug/page/78, the soldiers also had rum: "Too much money and too much rum necessarily affect the discipline of an army. We have glaring evidence of their ill consequences 
every moment. Serg'ts. drunk upon duty, 2 centries upon their posts 
and the rest wallowing in the dirt"